# Using Powershell, how do I filter a JSON to exclude certain key names?

Tags: json, powershell, large-files

I am trying to reduce the size of a JSON which is 700MB. It's a slightly smaller version of this: https://kaikki.org/dictionary/All%20languages%20combined/by-pos-name/kaikki_dot_org-dictionary-all-by-pos-name.json

I'm doing that by removing unnecessary information. The keys I don't need are: hypernyms,pos,categories,alt_of,inflection_templates,hyponyms,meronyms,source,wikipedia,holonyms,proverbs,head_templates,etymology_text,lang_code,hyphenation,forms,synonyms,antonyms.

I've tried

```
$Obj = 
  [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path -LiteralPath namesonly.json)) | 
  ConvertFrom-Json
$foo = Select-Object $Obj -ExcludeProperty hypernyms,pos,categories,alt_of,inflection_templates,hyponyms,meronyms,source,wikipedia,holonyms,proverbs,head_templates,etymology_text,lang_code,hyphenation,forms,synonyms,antonyms
$foo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 > namesonlycleaned.json
```

But this results in an empty file. How do I fix it so I'll get a new JSON without those unnecessary fields?

Edit: Suggested in comments to add an asterisk - If I got it right then

```
$Obj = 
  [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path -LiteralPath namesonly.json)) | 
  ConvertFrom-Json
$foo = Select-Object $Obj * -ExcludeProperty hypernyms,pos,categories,alt_of,inflection_templates,hyponyms,meronyms,source,wikipedia,holonyms,proverbs,head_templates,etymology_text,lang_code,hyphenation,forms,synonyms,antonyms
$foo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 > namesonlycleaned.json
```

Returns the error

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*'.
```

Comment: Change `$foo = Select-Object $Obj -ExcludeProperty ...` to `$foo = $Obj |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ...`

Comment: Thanks, trying it now. As it's such big file it's an hour or so to see if something works :/

Comment: @nemo - if it take an hour to run, maybe create yourself a smaller sample file for dev / test purposes :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen see edit, putting asterisk in throws an error.

Comment: @mclayton, good idea but not sure how to create one that is a valid JSON - how would I go about extracting the first object and turning into a JSON so I can test on that?

Comment: @NeMo Not `Select-Object $Obj * -ExcludeProperty`, but `$Obj |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty` - big difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your *immediate* problems are the ones pointed out by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):

  - Unfortunately, in *Windows PowerShell* the use of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-ExcludeProperty` *alone* does *not* work as intended (outputs empty objects) and requires combining with `-Property *` - this problem has been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)
  - Input objects must be provided to `Select-Object` *via the pipeline*:

    ```bash
    $Obj | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty hypernyms,pos,categories,alt_of,inflection_templates,hyponyms,meronyms,source,wikipedia,holonyms,proverbs,head_templates,etymology_text,lang_code,hyphenation,forms,synonyms,antonyms
    ```
- However, this alone will *not* solve your problem:

  - Judging by the linked data source and the array of properties you're trying to exclude, **some of those properties are those of *nested* objects**, i.e. **you're looking to remove properties from each object's *object graph***.
  - `Select-Object` doesn't support this, but the **custom `Remove-Property` function** (source code in the bottom section) does.

---

Use the following (make sure you've defined the `Remove-Property` function from the bottom section first):

```bash
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path -LiteralPath large.json)) | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  Remove-Property -Recurse -Property hypernyms,pos,categories,alt_of,inflection_templates,hyponyms,meronyms,source,wikipedia,holonyms,proverbs,head_templates,etymology_text,lang_code,hyphenation,forms,synonyms,antonyms |
  ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 > namesonlycleaned.json
```

Note:

- This will run for quite some time, but by using a *single pipeline* it avoids unnecessary memory use due to intermediate storage of results.

  - That said (at least as of PowerShell 7.4), `ConvertFrom-Json` reads *all input up front* before producing output; in terms of runtime performance, however, this part finishes fairly quickly.
- For troubleshooting - say to limit output to the first 10 objects - you can insert `Select-Object -First 10` as a pipeline segment before the `ConvertTo-Json` segment.

---

**`Remove-Property` source code**:

```bash
function Remove-Property {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Removes properties from [pscustomobject] or dictionary objects (hashtables)
  and outputs the resulting objects.
  
  .DESCRIPTION
  Use -Recurse to remove the specified properties / entries from 
  the entire object *graph* of each input object, i.e. also from any *nested* 
  [pscustomobject]s or dictionaries.

  Useful for removing unwanted properties / entries from object graphs parsed
  from JSON via ConvertFrom-Json.

  Attempts to remove non-existent properties / entries are quietly ignored.
  
  .EXAMPLE
  [pscustomobject] @{ foo=1; bar=2 } | Remove-Property foo

  Removes the 'foo' property from the given custom object and outputs the result.

  .EXAMPLE
  @{ foo=1; bar=@{foo=10; baz=2} } | Remove-Property foo -Recurse

  Removes 'foo' properties (entries) from the entire object graph, i.e. from
  the top-level hashtable as well as from any nested hashtables.
  #>
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)] [string[]] $Property,
    [switch] $Recurse,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [object] $InputObject
  )
  process {
    if (-not (($isPsCustObj = $InputObject -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) -or $InputObject -is [System.Collections.IDictionary])) { Write-Error "Neither a [pscustomobject] nor an [IDictionary] instance: $InputObject"; return }
    # Remove the requested properties from the input object itself.
    foreach ($propName in $Property) {
      # Note: In both cases, if  a property / entry by a given name doesn't exist, the .Remove() call is a quiet no-op.
      if ($isPsCustObj) {        
        $InputObject.psobject.Properties.Remove($propName)
      }
      else {
        # IDictionary
        $InputObject.Remove($propName)
      }
    }
    # Recurse, if requested.
    if ($Recurse) {
      if ($isPsCustObj) {
        foreach ($prop in $InputObject.psobject.Properties) {
          if ($prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] -or $prop.Value -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
            $prop.Value = Remove-Property -InputObject $prop.Value -Recurse -Property $Property
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        # IDictionary
        foreach ($entry in $InputObject.GetEnumerator()) {
          if ($entry.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] -or $entry.Value -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
            $entry.Value = Remove-Property -InputObject $entry.Value -Recurse -Property $Property
          }
        }
      }
    }
    $InputObject # Output the potentially modified input object.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi again :D. Thanks for all your help. Sorry it came in 3 bites - after each step I thought I'd be able to work out the next bit on my own - wrongly haha

Comment: @NeMo :) Glad to hear it helped. Your steps made for interesting questions.